# Logging jobs on a Google Cloud VM

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-stackdriver

I am using a Google Cloud virtual machine to run several python scripts scheduled on a cron, I am looking for some way to check that they ran.

When I look in my logs I see nothing, so I guess simply running a .py file is not logged? Is there a way to turn on logging at this level? What are the usual approaches for such things?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The technology for recording log information in GCP is called [Stackdriver](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/).  You have a couple of choices for how to log within your application.  The first is to instrument your code with Stackdriver APIs which explicitly write data to the Stackdriver subsytem.  [Here](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-python) are the docs for that and [here](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/setup/python) is further recipe.

A second story is that you install the [Stackdriver Logging Agent](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/) on your Compute Engine.  This will then allow you to tap into other sources of logging output such as local syslog.